# Can you split a file using ffmpeg directly from a db?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am splitting a file using ffmpeg and python. I am able split a file if I input a file path, but if I send in the file itself from my mongodb, it errors out. Is there a way to get ffmpeg to run using the file instead of the path to the file?

python code:

```
args = [ffmpeg_binary,
                         "-v", "quiet",
                         "-y", "-i", video_file, "-vcodec", "copy", "-acodec", "copy",
                 "-ss", "00:00:00", "-t", "00:00:10", "-sn",
                 output_file_name ]

pipe = sp.Popen(args)
```

if video_file is a `gridfs.grid_file.GridOut` object or a `(gridfs.grid_file.GridOut object).read()`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/youniversity/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    split_vid_from_file(vid_file)
  File "C:\dev\youniversity\src\lib\ffmpeg_lib.py", line 107, in split_vid_from_file
    pipe = sp.Popen(args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
TypeError: must be string without null bytes or None, not str
```

How do I split the video directly from the DB?

EDIT: I found that you can do this:

```
... "-y", "-", ... 

pipe = sp.Popen(args, stdin=sp.PIPE)
```

but I don't want the user to type input, I want to pipe in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use django-multimedia in order to split videos.

https://github.com/jbittel/django-multimedia

Comment: Why should I use their wrapper instead of what I had been doing? Is there a benefit?